# PnP.PowerShell create news link

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am currently exploring PnP.PowerShell and the ability to create and modify modern pages, but I have not been able to find any information on whether it's possible to create a News Link similar to what you can in the UI?

[image]

Any ideas?

**Updated**

Ok - so apparently news link is referred to as a Repost Page, so you can actually create a news link page with PowerShell like this:

```
Add-PnPPage -Name "test" -LayoutType RepostPage
```

But I have still not figured out how to set the repost page source URL and my fear is that this only supports reposting SharePoint pages so far.

I tried the following, but without any luck so far.

```
$Page = Add-PnPPage -Name "test" -LayoutType RepostPage
$Page.RepostSourceUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHTEc4XIF4Y"
$Page.Publish()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Save of the page with the modified properties before publishing it.
The following script will get your page published with everything you need.

$Page = Add-PnPPage -Name "test" -LayoutType RepostPage
$Page.RepostSourceUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHTEc4XIF4Y"
$Page.Save()
$Page.Publish()